# Is there a way to handle custom java exception in OSB?

Tags: java, osb, oracle-service-bus

For example, i created a exception that extends RuntimeException.
My exception has a new field called "code". I want to handle this exception in Oracle Service Bus process and retrieve this code to throws another exception with a XML structure that includes the code.
Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will be able to retrieve just the "code". But certainly you can retrieve the details of the exception which will include your code.

Try it out.

Comment: OK, in fault i have the error details. But it has a large message inside the element <reason>.
An interesting element that i found is <java-exception>, it contains a identifier to the object reference.
There are any way to retrieve that ?

Comment: Where did you find the element <java-exception>? As per the [Message Context Schema](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/doc.1111/e15867/context.htm#i1060633), I do not see this element defined.